# MySql FullText Search seems slow, How can I make this faster? Any Optimization required?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, full-text-search

I have a table with 1 million records and want to apply faster way to fetch record against any search query. As I am bad with mysql fulltext search.

I made following tests:

- Initially I applied `MATCH AGAINS` on single column it return result fast.
- Secondly I applied `MATCH AGAINS` on two columns and return very slow.
- Then I made column optimization and combined two columns into one and applied `MATCH AGAINS`on computed column. It returns very slow on first time but reasonably fast on second attempt with same search term.

Is there any issue with my query how I should amend this with more optimization?

```
 select name, meaning, m.gender, m.similar
        FROM
        NAMES n
        INNER JOIN meta m ON m.nameid = n.id
        WHERE MATCH (nameandmeaning) AGAINST ('searchterm*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
        AND meaning IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY LENGTH(m.similar) DESC
        LIMIT 0 , 10;
```

Note: `nameandmeaning` is combinition of `name, meaning`.

My Table Structure is as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE NAMES (
  id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  meaning VARCHAR(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  nameandmeaning VARCHAR(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id),
  FULLTEXT KEY constains_name(name,meaning),
  FULLTEXT KEY contains_namemeaing (nameandmeaning)
) ENGINE=MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=67846 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: please post the create from the Table

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE NAMES (
  id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  meaning VARCHAR(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  -- skip this:  nameandmeaning VARCHAR(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id),
  FULLTEXT KEY constains_name(name, meaning),
  -- skip this:  FULLTEXT KEY contains_namemeaing (nameandmeaning)
) ENGINE=MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=67846 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Then these should work fast:

```
MATCH(name) AGAINST (...)
MATCH(meaning) AGAINST (...)
MATCH(name, meaning) AGAINST (...)
```

When you upgrade to InnoDB, you should have all 3 of these (if you are doing all 3 of those MATCHes):

```
  FULLTEXT (name),
  FULLTEXT (meaning),
  FULLTEXT (name, meaning)
```